# Increasing the frequency of xticks in python seaborn plots

Tags: python, seaborn

I have plotted a FacetGrid plot of 15 subplots using Python seaborn Library. The number of data points in the x axis are 23 (0 t0 23). I want all of them to be displayed on the x axis.
Here is the plot code-

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(dataset, col="City",col_wrap=4 ,height=4, aspect=1.5)
g = g.map(sns.lineplot, "Block",'temp_error',color='#EE0000')
```

Here is a snapshot of the graph-
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set readable xticks in seaborn's facetgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727278/how-to-set-readable-xticks-in-seaborns-facetgrid)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the xticks using the following command. You have to pass a list of xticks in the *xticks* argument.

```
g.set(xticks=np.arange(24))
```

Hope this helps.